Avoid creation of duplicate container (kustomize patch)
I have a kustomize patch which looks like this:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: foo-system
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: ghcr.io/foo/bar

there are two cases: there is already a container with name "backend", or there is no such container.
As an author of the kustomize patch, I want always to do an update.
Is there a way to get an error from kustomize if the patch would do a "create"?
Background: Names got changed, and then we had two containers in the deployment, because one place was not updated. I would like this to fail early the next time.
